# Ошибка в реализации INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть класс ViewModel который реализует INPC. Есть публичное свойство `TextToSend` к которому биндится текстбокс.

```
<TextBox Height="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{Binding TextToSend, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Реализация интерфейса :

```
class ClientChatModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Свойство к которому идет привязка :

```
    public string TextToSend
    {
        get
        {
            return _texttosend;
        }
        set
        {
            _texttosend = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextToSend");
        }
    }
    private string _texttosend { get; set; }
```

Ошибок не выдает, не вылетает но если выполняется какая либо команда призванная очистить текстбокс - т.е. очистить _texttosend к которому привязано свойство `Text` контрола интерфейс не получает уведомления и текст  контрола остается хотя свойство уже изменилось. В чем у меня ошибка ?

Comment: А как вы очищаете? Попробуйте так: `TextToSend = ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чую, что вы очищаете ваше свойство `_texttosend` (почему бы не сделать его переменной, кстати?) вместо свойства `TextToSend`.

Попробуйте очищать так:

```
TextToSend = String.Empty;
```

Comment: Догадался уже.) Но все равно спасибо, почуяли правильно плюс за это!